# Life cycle of local Java objects created during a method call

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In a method call, if I create an object during that call.   When are those objects garbage collected?

Are they placed on the heap and then garbage collected along with other objects on the heap.  Or are they garbage collected earlier because they are not needed.  The execution of that method has completed.

Answer (score 6):

Objects created within method scope are eligible for garbage collection when the method is closed - unless that reference is passed back as the return value.  In that case, the caller may or may not hang onto that reference and prevent it from being gc'd.

Since the garbage collector runs on its own thread according to its own lights, you don't necessarily know when an object is cleaned up, or whether or not objects allocated elsewhere are eligible as well.

Comment: @duffymo:Doesn't this depend on whether the newly created object's reference exists after return of the function?E.g. an object stored in a collection that is in the caller's scope.

Comment: @user - In that case the scope of the object has changed, and may not be affected by GC.

Comment: "Objects created within method scope..." to me means that it was not passed in by the user.  You're right about one thing: if the object created in scope is passed back as the return value, then the caller may hold onto the reference and prevent it from being gc'd.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: THe object can escape in many other ways, not only as return value. Every time you call a method on the object or have it used as a method parameter you can no longer trivially determine object lifecycle.

Comment: @mtraut, can you give details about the other means of escape?  Method parameters are different, because the caller has a reference to them when you start.  I'm thinking about objects that are created in method scope.  I can imagine that anything done inside the method to create a long-lasting reference (e.g., adding a local reference to a cache, etc.), but I had the most likely scenario in mind when I wrote my response.

Comment: what i mean is that the system can not trivialy make a difference between (where is the line break :-) Object m1()  { Object a = new Thing(); return null; } and Object m2()   { Object a = new Thing(); a.toString(); return null; }, where in "toString" the new object is assigned to a static variable. Same holds for "b.anotherCall(a)"...  Or are we talking about different things?

Comment: The new Thing is not assigned to a static variable in the second case; a String representation is created and added to the String pool, but that's not hanging onto a reference to "a" as far as I know.  Object "a" will be gc'd after the method m2() is exited, because there are no objects holding a reference to it.

Comment: @duffymo, thats exactly why i have used this example (i know about the standard protocol for toString :-)) What you THINK this method does has nothing to do with what it really does. What keeps you from writing a method "toString" that caches because of very expensive computations the string in a static map (no discussion about bad style). It's just that the machine does NOT know by looking at the method. Its simply about control flow. If a method is called that has ANY reference (receiver or parameter) to the new object, the system is out of luck.

Comment: Wow - I'm going to have to investigate this.

Answer (score 3):

This is not so easy - in the very end every object is created in some method.

The VM / compiler needs to make escape path analysis to detect if a reference of this object in some way can escape - imagine calling newObject.toString(). You and me know (hope) that this will do no harm and the object is still not referenced, as it will not link itself to a global variable. But the VM dows not.

While a modern VM will do such analysis and treat real short lived objects special in garbage collection, from a "high level" point of view they are just objects. Everything else is sophisticated low level optimization.

And anyway, as duffymo says - when exactly this objects are freed is uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the execution of the method has ended and now the object is out of scope is irrelevant.
Garbage collection is an implicit operation of the runtime system running in a separate thread in parallel with your code, implementing a specific garbage collection algorithm.
The garbage collection thread runs at unpredictable times-but very often, every second or so according to java docs and when the memory is almost run out, evaluating which objects are eligible to be garbage collected i.e. there are no references to them from root pointers e.g. static variables.
So every object accessible by a root pointer is marked and then recursively the objects referenced by these objects etc.
This can mean scanning the entire process space. Once done, all the objects not "marked" from previous scan go to the free list (are GC'd).
This is a heavy operation as you can see.

> The execution of that method has
>   completed.

So the fact that you are out of the scope of a method you called because it has completed, is irrelevant. It does not mean that the runtime knows at that point that the object is done (since GC is run in parallel).
It is not like in C++ that in the end of the method the programmer would call delete on the object since it is not needed. No "delete" is automatically called at the end of the method in Java.
The GC thread will eventually realize that there are no more references to the object allocated on the heap by the method and CG it.
You can call the GC at any point if you want by:

```
System.gc();
```

But the GC will run sooner or later anyway.
One thing to note is as long as there is a reference to a method by a root pointer it can not be GC's.
So if in your method you create via `new` an object on the heap and you store the reference in a container that is static or return it to the caller, the object outlives the method.

Comment: Garbage collection has improved a lot since the days of Smalltalk. No commercial grade VM does it like this any longer. A lot of infos can be google about actual algorithms.

Comment: System.gc() is more or less a suggestion to the VM that it would be a good idea now to trigger a gc. You can' t rely that this is acknowledged AND (even if the VM agrees) you can rely that after gc() garbage is collected. This is always asynchronous.

Comment: @mtraut:I am leaning towards this also.But the javadocs seem to say otherwise:`When control returns from the method call (System.gc), the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects`

Comment: the sentence in my comment should read "(even if the VM agrees) you CAN'T rely ...". Exactly as you cited, its best effort. This means its up to the VM - who knows best.

Comment: To be picky about your first sentence: the object has NOT gone out of scope - the variable that references it has gone out of scope. And this is more or less the source of all the confusion around this area.