# Life time of local variable in Java

Tags: java, class, object

```
     public List<Map<String,class1>> methodName(String Parameter)
     {
          //create instance of List
          List<Map<Strig,class1>> list1 = new ArrayList<Map<String,class1>>();

          for(ArrayList arrayList : someGlobalList)
          {
              //create instance of class1
              //Initialize class1 with values in arrayList
              //Put this class1 as a value to tempMap which is created inside this loop
              //Put that tempMap into List
          }
       return list1;
     }
```

**My doubt**

I understand that we cannot guarantee garbage collection. But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557209/life-cycle-of-local-java-objects-created-during-a-method-call) says that `when we return a local reference` that will not be garbage collected. In my case, class1 is a local Object. But I am returning `list1`. Is it safe to use those objects from the caller function as `list1.get("key")`. It will return the `class1` Object. Can I safely use the class members?

Comment: `"Can I safely use the class members?"` -- yes. There is a valid way to gain a reference to all the items held by the List, and they will not be GC'd.

Comment: The rule of thumb for garbage collection is this: anything you can access from any part of the application through (strong) references will **not** be collected. That means you don't ever need to worry about objects disappearing without a trace. You sometimes however need to worry about too many retained objects, but that's a different question. (The above only applies to "normal" references, there are specialised ways to keep a more tentative, soft or weak reference to an object.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object is only eligible for garbage collection after the last reference to it is no longer reachable from your code.

Let's count the references to your newly created object. Each `class1` object is only referenced from the list at the moment, so let's look at the references to the list itself.

You have one reference called `list1`.

Then you return a value. This creates a *second* reference, which is placed in the stack and passed up to the caller.

```
List<...> result = theObj.methodName("foo");
```

During that process the first reference (`list1`) is no longer accessible, but the reference that was returned back is still accessible - it will be assigned to the variable `result` in this case. So you still have one valid and accessible reference to the list. Therefore, every reference inside the list is also valid and accessible.

So yes, it is completely safe to use.

There are languages other than Java, where you can allocate an object in *stack* space. That is, the object itself is allocated locally. Returning a reference to such an object is unsafe as the stack frame is popped. Take this example in C, that returns a pointer to the beginning of a local array:

```
char *bad_string(void)
{
    /* BAD BAD BAD */
    char buffer[] = "local string";
    return buffer;
}
```

But in Java, objects are always allocated in heap space (barring internal optimizations which are not visible to the programmer and are checked to be safe, as mentioned in the comments).

An object allocated by the `new` operator is never "popped", and always obeys the rules of garbage collection. Stack/local method space is only used for primitives and references, and you never get a reference to any of those, only to objects. Thus, if you have a reference to something, you can trust that its memory is safe.

Comment: Actually, JVMs can (and [will](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis)) allocate objects on stack. But only when it can be ascertained that a reference to them can't escape.

Comment: @biziclop - Agreed, *escape analysis* can bring about *Stack allocation* but it doesn't happen always. It is just another JIT optimization.

Comment: @biziclop Thank you. From the point of view of the programmer, though, it can be said that there is no such thing as a locally-allocated object.

Comment: @TheLostMind And most importantly, you've got no direct control over it like in C++.

Comment: @biziclop - My point exactly.. It cannot be guaranteed that for the same JVM and the same set of objects, stack allocation can happen for successive runs :)

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Actually from a programmers perspective, there are things called as *stack allocated objects* but the thing is *JIT might decide to allocate an object on the stack ONLY IF its reference is not leaking from the current method*. Thats the whole point of escape analysis. :)

Comment: Absolutely. I think the take home message of this is that a lot of the rules of Java are deliberately formulated this way: "X **always appears to** behave like Y", to allow for behind the scenes optimisations. But whether those optimisations happen or not is up to the JVM and can't be **directly** influenced (or detected) through code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll be able to access all the objects contained in the list object (`list1`) you are returning (including objects of type `class1`) as long as its reference is assigned to a reference variable in the method that called `methodName`.
This is because there is no such thing as a *local object*. Objects live in the heap (unlike local variables which live on the stack) and they will only be eligible for garbage collection if there are no more reachable references to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The moment list1 leaves the frame ( is returned by the function ), it and all of it's references stop being "local variables" and will not be candidates for garbage collection until there are no longer any references to "list1"

Answer (score 0):

> In my case, class1 is a local Object. But I am returning list1

If a reference *leaks* from a method, then that object can be used (*safely*? is again another question which is dependent on the exact definition of *safe*). In your case since you are returning `list1`, all local fields referenced by `list1` (recursively) can be accessed without NPE (or the fear of them being GCed) because your list has a *strong reference* to those instances.

If you are talking about thread safety, then it depends on how many threads have access to this *leaked* reference(s).

Answer (score -1):

You need to have only one reference. Objects referenced by this first referenced object will be free from GC as well.. and so on up the tree.